# IBMPush for iOS Application : Error code 404

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud

I am trying to implement push notification for iOS using IBMPush service.
While sending the message I am getting the following error -

```
Notification Error  { [HttpRequestError: Server responded with an error status: 404]
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT   name: 'HttpRequestError',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT   message: 'Server responded with an error status: 404',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT   info: 
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT    { statusCode: 404,
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT      responseText: '404 Not Found: Requested route (\'push.ng.bluemix.net\') does not exist.\n',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT      requestHeaders: 
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT       { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Application-ID': 'myAppID',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Application-Secret': 'mysecret',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Device-Type': 'WEB',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Device-ID': 'myDeviceID',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Device-Model': 'linux',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Device-Platform-Version': 'Node Version: v0.12.7',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Device-Name': 'Node v0.12.7, Platform: linux, Arch: x64',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'IBM-Request-Correlation-ID': 1439529300696,
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         'X-REWRITE-DOMAIN': 'ng.bluemix.net' },
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT      requestOptions: 
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT       { handleAs: 'json',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         contentType: 'json',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         timeout: 30000,
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         url: 'https://marketplaceuberapplication.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/3f5c0150-d0a8-4f4c-ac5c-973368d163a9/messages',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         method: 'post',
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         headers: [Object],
2015-08-14T10:45:00.74+0530 [App/0]   OUT         body: '{"message":{"alert":"Your profile is matching with ViSA9048 Opportunity."},"target":{"deviceIds":["55cc7a311fde007c80c3cadf"]},"settings":{"apns":{"payload":{"message":"Hello to iOS devices"},"badge":1,"sound":""}}}' } }enter code here
```

Comment: How are you sending the push request? Via the Push console? API Swagger Doc? Device side? Postman?

Can you please explain a little further on how you are accomplishing this so I can investigate. Also in the requestHeaders are you providing the  App ID, secret and device id? (I am assuming you just removed them in the question)

Comment: When I send via push console then it works fine. I got the notification using push console provided by Bluemix.

Comment: I have developed a code of sending push notification in nodejs according requirements and I am using deviceid to send the push notification using notify method provided by IBMPush service. While executing that code it gives the above error. I have provided the  App ID, secret and  route in both the applications(backend and frontend) and I am getting the device id from frontend application.

Comment: Can you provide the Node.js code you are using?

Comment: I agree with Dave I think you need to provide your node.js code. What worries me is the 404 you are receiving is the following:

 responseText: '404 Not Found: Requested route (\'push.ng.bluemix.net\') does not exist.\n'

I see that your application is actually located here though:
https://marketplaceuberapplication.eu-gb.mybluemix.net...

Do you see the push route you are attempting to access is in the US while the app is in London?

Comment: Jaalger, you are rigth. The API-endpoint which I am using might not having IBM push service that's why it is giving me this error.